# Documenting API with Swagger

Tags: scala, playframework, swagger

I'm new in Swagger. I have an API and I want to document it with Swagger based on model, not on annotation. Please provide some guide how can I do it? Thanks in advance! I need literature, examples, tutorial etc.

Comment: Your questions really lacks details. I realize you've added tags that may be relevant to the question, but you need to provide versions of the tools you use and so on. I think the question is a bit too vague to SO and would be better addressed in Swagger's google group.

Comment: Well all three technologies with last versions. I have to implement an API using scala, swagger and play framework with last versions. I'm completely new in these three. I don't have any idea how should I start it. Would be appreciated if you could guide me. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know what's the last version of play. It's better to be explicit. Right now, you can only integrate swagger core 1.3 with play. There's no proper documentation but check the sample https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/tree/v1.3.12/samples/scala-play2

Comment: I'm working with 2.11 version. The material provided in this link is kind of complicated, I'm looking for more easier one.

Comment: That's the version of scala, not play. In any case, that's the documentation there is. Perhaps the google group has some more elaborate descriptions, try searching it.

Comment: Mmmm sorry, I'm using 2.3.8 version. You were right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swagger is the easiest way to create REST API documentation and the sand box for your API, You need to just follow some annotation rule defined by swagger API.

You have to learn the following thing first-

1. Basic REST API concepts
2. REST API with Play.
3. Look in Swagger annotations.

You can see the demo at http://petstore.swagger.io/

To understand the flow see in the following files

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play-sample-app/blob/master/app/controllers/PetController.scala

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-play-sample-app/blob/master/conf/routes